# Создать форму внутри формы C#

Tags: c#

Мне хотелось бы создать окно внутри программы на C#.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот типо того

Comment: Это называется MDI.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А можно MDI засунуть только в определённую область а не вовсю форму?

Comment: @Redis нет но можно сделать отдельным всплывающим окном например.